# Копирование массива в СИ

Tags: c, массивы

У меня есть заданный массив array_1, можно как то создать точно такой же массив array_2? или это придется делать в цикле с i?

Comment: Приведи пример того, что не получилось. Это "превентивный" вопрос. То есть из серии "я ничего не попробовал, скажите, можно ли так попробовать"? Ответ: можно. Пробуй. Если не получится, покажи проблемное место. Пока выглядит как попытка узнать решение для учебного задания. Я отмечаю как "Рекомендовать закрытие" вопроса. Дальше пусть модераторы решают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужен цикл.

Еще можно использовать `memcpy` (внутри которого скорее всего тоже находится цикл).

Еще вариант: завернуть массив в структуру: `struct Foo {int array[10];};` - такую структуру можно копировать в одну строчку, без цикла.

Comment: Интересно, гда проходит граница (понятно, что она зависит от -O) между чтением-записью нескольких регистров и вызовом memcpy